# JS - keyboard events - listen / unlisten

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have an issue concerning the keyboards events in JS.

First of all, **please do not answer me to use jQuery methods**, I know most of it (bind/unbind, on/off, one...) but I work with an internal framework that **have to work without jQuery**, even if jQuery is used on most of our projects.

So, I have a module, in fact a swipe tool based on [Swipe.js](http://swipejs.com/) and extended to work on web and mobile environments (compatibility needed for IE 7+, WebKit (Chrome & Safari), Moz, Opera and IE10 / Windows Phone)

In do not have any problem with mouse/touch events, the binding and unbinding methods inspired from [the mobile HTML5 BP](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/blob/master/js/helper.js#L216) seems to work very well with a small correction for the detachEvents method.

And then I would to implement a keyboard control feature based on 'keydown' events.
(BTW, I am not sure to make a good difference between keydon and keypress events, except the keypressEvent.preventDefault() do not prevent the small scroll effect, so I use keydown.)

As it is possible to add many Swipes on the same page, I start to listen the keydown events only when any Swipe is focused (Note that I add a "tabindex" attribute to allow the element to get focused).

```
<div id="swipe1" class="swipe" tabindex='0'>
    <ul>
        [...]
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then when the Swipe handle a 'touchstart' / 'click' / ' MSPointerDown' event,
I focus it :

```
onTouchStart: function(e) {
    this.container.focus(); // Refers to the div#swipe1.swipe element
    [...]
    return false;
}

onFocus: function (e) {
    if (this.activateKeyboardControls) { // Keyboard control is optional
        this.addListener(document, 'keydown', this, true);
    }
}

onBlur: function (e) {
    if (this.activateKeyboardControls) { // Keyboard control is optional
        this.removeListener(document, 'keydown', this, true);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, the removeListener does not work.

I mean, when the element loses the focus (blur event fired), it still handle the keydown events...

Is it because it is binded on the document object ?
I have read some solutions working with some booleans but I am looking for a cleaner way the manage it.

This is annoying, because when I give the focus to many Swipes, each of them is swiping when I press the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the reason why my answer has been deleted - more than 2 weeks after posting - but anyway, this is how I solved it :

It comes from the 'type' parameter of the addEventListener / attachEvent method, the first of one so...

I bind it on the object instead of on the window, and without bubbling.

```
var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
if (this.activateKeyboardControls) {
    this.addListener(target, 'keydown', this, false);
}
```